# How to decrypt hash password using C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a old database where password is in Hashed format,i need to decrypt hashed password.Is there any method in membership to decrypt hash password.

Answer (score 1):

The hash is probably designed to be one way. If you know the hashing algorithm used you could use brute force, but otherwise no, there is no way to "decrypt" the password.